# Spring dependency integration with Selenium

Tags: java, spring, selenium

I don't know why, but Spring don't @Autowired my dependencies and I always get NullPoionterException. I get exception in initializeDriver method on chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");. I'm creating WebDriver using factory pattern like this.

```
public abstract class DriverManager {

    protected WebDriver webDriver;
    protected abstract void initializeDriver();

    public void quitDriver() {
        if (webDriver != null) {
            webDriver.quit();
            webDriver = null;
        }
    }

    public WebDriver getWebDriver() {
        return webDriver;
    }
}
@Component
public class ChromeDriverManager extends DriverManager {

    @Autowired
    private DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities;

    @Autowired
    private ChromeOptions chromeOptions;

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences;


    protected void initializeDriver() {
        desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("-incognito");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

        loggingPreferences = new LoggingPreferences();
        loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPreferences);
        webDriver = beanFactory.getBean(ChromeDriver.class, desiredCapabilities);
    }
}

@Component
public class DriverManagerFactory {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("ChromeDriverManager")
    private DriverManager chromeDriverManager;

    public DriverManager getManager(Browser browser) {
        DriverManager driverManager;
        switch (browser) {
            case CH:
                chromeDriverManager.initializeDriver();
                driverManager = chromeDriverManager;
                break;
            default:
                //todo rest of browsers
                driverManager = null;
        }
        return driverManager;
    }
}

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "tmp")
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    @Lazy
    public ChromeDriver chromeDriver(DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ATF\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
        return new ChromeDriver(desiredCapabilities);
    }

    @Bean
    public DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities() {
        return new DesiredCapabilities();
    }

    @Bean
    public ChromeOptions chromeOptions() {
        return new ChromeOptions();
    }

    @Bean
    public LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences() {
        return new LoggingPreferences();
    }
}

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class runChrome {

    @Autowired
    DriverManagerFactory driverManagerFactory;

    DriverManager driverManager;

    @Before
    public void beforeTest() {
        driverManager = driverManagerFactory.getManager(Browser.CH);
    }


    @Test
    public void run() {
        driverManager.getWebDriver().get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

Did I need some annotation on my ChromeDriverManager class or what? I don't get it. My first approach was without factory pattern and all work fine. But I do all things in my test class and it look like this.

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = AppConfig.class)
public class runChrome {

    @Autowired
    private BeanFactory beanFactory;

    @Autowired
    private DesiredCapabilities desiredCapabilities;

    @Autowired
    private LoggingPreferences loggingPreferences;

    @Autowired
    private ChromeOptions chromeOptions;

    @Test
    public void run() {
        desiredCapabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        chromeOptions = new ChromeOptions();
        chromeOptions.addArguments("test-type");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        chromeOptions.addArguments("-incognito");
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, chromeOptions);

        loggingPreferences = new LoggingPreferences();
        loggingPreferences.enable(LogType.BROWSER, Level.ALL);
        desiredCapabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.LOGGING_PREFS, loggingPreferences);
        ChromeDriver chromeDriver = beanFactory.getBean(ChromeDriver.class, desiredCapabilities);
        chromeDriver.get("http://www.google.com");
    }
}
```

My application config don't change. I use the same in both scenarios.
**Edit:** I have edited my code to suggestions. But still I get this ugly exception.

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'driverManagerFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'chromeDriverManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tmp.DriverManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ChromeDriverManager)}
May 12, 2017 1:20:37 PM org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager prepareTestInstance
SEVERE: Caught exception while allowing TestExecutionListener [org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@47f6473] to prepare test instance [tmp.runChrome@2e005c4b]
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'driverManagerFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'chromeDriverManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tmp.DriverManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ChromeDriverManager)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tmp.DriverManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ChromeDriverManager)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 42 more


java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext

    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'driverManagerFactory': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'chromeDriverManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tmp.DriverManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ChromeDriverManager)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:128)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:251)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:116)
    ... 24 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'tmp.DriverManager' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=ChromeDriverManager)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Couple of points

1. You need to have `@Component`(or anything equivalent) on `ChromeDriverManager` class. Without this none of your fields will be Autowired since it will not be scanned at all.
2. In your `DriverManagerFactory` class you are doing `new ChromeDriverManager()` if you create instance using new then you lose spring autowiring capabilities and all the fileds inside this new object you created will be null(even if you put @Component on ChromeDriverManager)
   So you need to Autowire `ChromeDriverManager` in your `DriverManagerFactory` class. And of course make `DriverManagerFactory` class a bean using @Component(similar to point 1)

Comment: OK, so should I remove my factory and create drivers in AppConfig?

Comment: No. Your design is perfect. You need @Component on ChromeDriverManager and DriverManagerFactory and in DriverManagerFactory don't create new object using new. Instead Autowire ChromeDriverManager   

`@Autowired
@Qualifier("ChromeDriverManager")
DriverManager ChromeDriverManager`  

And In your tesr class Autowire DriverManagerFactory and call getManager

Comment: I just edit code and i still get exceptions :( I don't get why? I even tried to add @Component on DriverManager but still don't work.

Comment: I get It. Fixed `DriverManager chromeDriverManager` to `ChromeDriverManager chromeDriverManager` and it works. But now if I want more browsers did I have to `@Autowire` them all?

Comment: yes. In your factory, you have to  autowire all and then return the right driver based on the browser.  You should always use interface(`DriverManager`) and not use implementing classes(`ChromeDriverManager`) when declaring. You should use `DriverManager` with @Qualifier. I see your updated code. you have used `@Qualifier("ChromeDriverManager")` but the name inside Qualifier should be `chromeDriverManager`(with smaller case 'c' not 'C'). This is because when spring create your bean for class ABC it gives the name automatically as aBC(first letter Smaller). You can customize that also. explore

Comment: You can customize the name you want. I will leave that for you to explore